# K8s Control Plane Fault-tolerance | Minimum nodes and Leader Election

Tags: kubernetes, high-availability, etcd, fault-tolerance

On a stacked (etcd+master on the same node) control plane setup we need a minimum of 3 nodes to achieve Quorum but what is the requirement for a setup where we have external etcd nodes? Etcd needs a minimum of 3 but what is the minimum number of master nodes we need?

The [official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/ha-topology/) says a minimum of 3 is required but it is confusing as the leader election/consensus algorithm used for etcd and master nodes are different so it is not very clear as to what is the minimum number of master nodes required to achieve fault-tolerance.

> However, this topology requires twice the number of hosts as the stacked HA topology. A minimum of three hosts for control plane nodes and three hosts for etcd nodes are required for an HA cluster with this topology.

Thanks in advance!

### Edits

Kubernetes Version: 1.17.0

ETCD Version: 3.3.12

Comment: What version are you using of Kubernetes and etcd?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak Sorry, I should've added this in the first place; Find it on the edit section of the question.

Comment: You are using [unsupported version](https://endoflife.date/kubernetes) of [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/releases/). However, you did refer to the most recent documentation. Which algorithms are you saying are different?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak, Thanks for letting me know. Essentially I want to know the minimum number of control plane nodes that are required to achieve fault tolerance in a setup with external etcd nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Official [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/ha-topology/#external-etcd-topology) conforms to [etcd's recommendations](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.3/faq/#what-is-failure-tolerance): to achieve fault tolerance of at least one node in etcd cluster, the etcd cluster size needs to be of at least 3 nodes (odd number). The same minimum is specified in the Kubernetes documentation (min 3 nodes dedicated to etcd cluster = the same number as master nodes).

You can also empirically test it yourself using [this article](https://zhimin-wen.medium.com/testing-of-etcd-failure-936dc5833a62).

Comment: Thanks, Mikolaj, I was referring to the same document as well. I am quite clear on etcd's requirement of 3 nodes as it is using Raft as the consensus algorithm and Raft needs (n/2)+1 nodes to achieve quorum. However, I am unsure as to why a minimum of 3 master nodes is required and if there is an underlying reason for that decision.

Comment: The number 3 is the smallest number that will satisfy (n/2)+1. Let's go one by one. For 1, we have (1/2)+1, that is 0+1=1. We have 1 node and the same 1 node is needed for the quorum. For the number 2: (2/2)+1 that is 1+1=2. As above, we have 2 nodes and the same 2 nodes are needed to reach the quorum. For 3 we have (3/2)+1, which gives 1+1, which is 2. To achieve the quorum for 3 nodes, 2 nodes are enough. This way we got the failure rate on 1. Read [this page](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.3/faq/#what-is-failure-tolerance) for more info. You can find good comparison table.

Comment: Thanks, Mikolaj
I should've been more clear. I understand the need for 3 nodes for etcd as it establishes quorum but I have not found anywhere that the master node(controller+scheduler+api) is using quorum or any algorithm that needs 3 minimum nodes to achieve fault tolerance.

Comment: [Here](https://netapp-trident.readthedocs.io/en/stable-v19.01/dag/kubernetes/kubernetes_cluster_architecture_considerations.html#multiple-master-compute) you can find a doc with explanation.