# Fault tolerance in HA k3s setup

Tags: kubernetes, high-availability, etcd, fault-tolerance, k3s

I'm trying to setup an HA k3s cluster with embedded etcd as datastore, with some VMs running on a server and a few raspberry pis.

I think I understand all of the concepts behind kubernetes and k3s specifically, but there is one thing I do not understand, which is how many servers (etcd, control-plane) can go offline for the cluster to still function. I've tried finding more info on this topic [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68178282/k8s-control-plane-fault-tolerance-minimum-nodes-and-leader-election) post, but nothing seems to answer my question:

If I have 3 servers in the cluster, will the cluster still function with only a single server online and the other 2 offline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know nothing about k3s and only a little about k8s, but from etcd perspective https://etcd.io/docs/v3.5/faq/#what-is-failure-tolerance is answering your question quite well.

TL;DR;

You need majority of servers in the cluster to be online for the cluster to work, thus you need at least 3 servers in a cluster to survive one server going offline.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

In a 3-node cluster, 1 node can fail and the cluster will still run.

If you check [here](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.3/faq/) you will see the fault tolerace of a 3-node cluster is 1 - i.e. 1 node can fail and the cluster will still run,.

| Cluster Size | Majority | Failure Tolerance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 2 |
| 6 | 4 | 2 |